# Blackberry BrowserField character encoding problem

Tags: blackberry, character-encoding

How can i solve character encoding problem in BrowserField? Some of UTF-8 characters (like 'ş', 'ç'...) appear as '?' character.

Comment: Can you check the server really sends data in UTF-8? Does the server response `Content-Type` header contain `charset=UTF-8`?

Comment: Actually i can't even type these character into EditField or somewhere else. I think it is about device language.

I tried to add language parameter to the xml file of simulator. It didn't work.

Comment: If you're using a generic simulator, then you could also try to use a wireless operator specific simulator. For instance, RIM has a Bold 9780 sim for Orange France. I think that sim should allow to enter non-ASCII chars they use in France.

Comment: Ok, i will try one of them. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a very good Solution

```
Browserfield browserField = new BrowserField();
browserField.requestContent(PATH);
browserField.displayContent(byte,"text/html; charset=utf-8", "http://localhost");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might solve your problem

```
browserField.requestContent(localFilePath);
browserField.displayContent(responseData,"text/html; charset=utf-8", "http://localhost");
```